# CLion cmake glew error?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glew

I ma trying to setup glew for clion but for some reason everything I have tried after researching the subject seems to not work and produce errors. I have downloaded the source files from their main website http://glew.sourceforge.net/ and are located within my clion project under directory `Externals`. Note: there is for some reason nothing under the lib folder under glew. my assumption build be that cmake builds it then links it which would be fine but I am very new to cmake and have no idea if this is the case.

CMake compile errors

```
C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\171.4073.41\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\SkyGames
-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing:  VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Using Win32 for window creation
-- Could NOT find GLEW (missing:  GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY) 
-- Configuring done
CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:glew>

  TARGET_PDB_FILE is not supported by the target linker.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Matt/CLionProjects/SkyGames/cmake-build-debug
```

CMakeList for project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(SkyGames)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(SkyGames ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/GLFW3)

###########################
# GLFW
###########################

target_link_libraries(SkyGames glfw)
include_directories(SkyGames ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})

###########################
# GLEW
###########################

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/glew2s/build/cmake)

find_package(glew REQUIRED)
if (GLEW_FOUND)
    include_directories(SkyGames ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

##########################
# OPENGL
##########################

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(SkyGames ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY})

include_directories(SkyGames ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

***Update:***

It appears that the new version of the CMakeLists.txt works fine except when you build the program it errors saying permission denied. it is further highlighted below.

new GLEW portion of CmakeList.txt

```
###########################
# GLEW
###########################
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/glew2s/build/cmake)
set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/glew2s/include)
set(GLEW_LIBRARY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/glew2s/lib)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/glew2s/include)

##########################
# OPENGL
##########################

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(SkyGames GLEW::GLEW ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY})
```

Build Message

```
C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\171.4073.41\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\SkyGames\cmake-build-debug --target SkyGames -- -j 8
[ 71%] Built target glfw
[ 76%] Linking CXX executable SkyGames.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ../Externals/glew2s/lib: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [SkyGames.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\SkyGames.dir\build.make:206: recipe for target 'SkyGames.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SkyGames.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SkyGames.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SkyGames.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [SkyGames] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SkyGames.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:161: recipe for target 'SkyGames' failed
```

Comment: It doesn't find Vulkan nor Glew. Install them. IDE isn't relevant for whether it finds those or not. If you're on Linux, then both above tasks are easy (on recent distributions).

Comment: im actually on windows. I know that it doesnt find vulkan but that is just a cmake flag for glfw which I can worry about later as glfw works perfectly fine right now. I just cannot seem to figure out the problem with glew.

Comment: Gro grab GLEW from their website and then point CMake at it with `-D` through command-line. Read the FingGLEW module docs for the stuff you need to define.

Comment: okay i think I understand what you are saying but like I said I am very new to cmake so I am not really sure what I would be looking for in the FindGLEW. also I have tried so many different "solutions" I found online that I am extremely confused since none of them work

Comment: okay I think I got it but it now says that when I compile it says "permission denied" on the glew lib folder. not really sure what the issue is now. in the cmake when compiling it says it finds glew and opengl so it must be working

Comment: Try running cmake as admin. And make sure that the GLEW folder is reachable and doesn't require admin permissions to access.

Comment: running as admin still gives the same error. the exact error is `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ../Externals/glew2s/lib: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. Not really sure why it cannot find the folder as it is the correct path..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142094/discussion-between-matthew-and-tambre).